Intermittent "Cannot access target document location with the current permissions" error with Azure Translator API
We've been experiencing an intermittent issue with the Azure Translator API and need some help troubleshooting. Most of the time, everything works fine, but occasionally, when trying to check the status of a batch translation operation, we get the following error:
Cannot access target document location with the current permissions.
I could understand this if it were a constant permission issue, but the error doesn't happen consistently.
Here’s how we are sending the translation request:
We make a request to Azure via https://xxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/translator/text/batch/v1.1/batches, and Azure returns an operation-location.
Using the operation-location URL, we check the status of our translation.
For example, we received an operation-location such as https://xxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/translator/text/batch/v1.1/batches/df7a305c-a35c-4f87-be48-dd33befb8002, and when we tried to retrieve the status of the translation, we encountered the following error:
Cannot access target document location with the current permissions.
Has anyone encountered this issue or knows how to resolve it? Any insights on why this could be happening intermittently?
Thanks in advance for your help!
